# Rails 5.1.4 | I18N: Translating model attributes with space between words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to translate:

```
<%= t(User.human_attribute_name("phone_number")) %>
```

In `en.yml` I have:

```
activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        phone_number: "Phone number"
```

And in rendered view I get "Phone Number" and:

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.Phone number">
    Phone Number
</span>
```

If I provide one word `phone_number: "Phonenumber"` it gets rendered correctly. If I provide several words as translation in common situation — everything works fine.

**Is it bug or what am I doing wrong?**

Edit 1:
[Rails guides for Translations for Active Record Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

Comment: human_attribute_name removes the underscore and replaces it with a " "  (space) but in your en.yml the object is still called phone_number (without underscore) so it can't find it

Comment: `User.human_attribute_name(:some_attr)` already returns the translation, so don't try to translate the translation, just use `User.human_attribute_name('phone_number')`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, why not model attributes `<%= t(:connected_profiles) %>` and `connected_profiles: "Connected profiles"` work fine? (it renders "... profiles" not "... Profiles"). Edit: "not model attributes"

Comment: `t(:connected_profiles)` will look for the translation located in `en.connected_profiles`. You could do `t('activerecord.attributes.user.phone_number')` but it is basically the same thing as `User.human_attribute_name(:phone_number)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, and (anyway) why first one does work fine (I tried also this explicit notation, and it returns correct translation) and the second one does not (says there is no translation, when it is there)?

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I finally understood the problem and realised that you were talking about it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in using `t()`

Just use `Model.human_attribute_name()` and it returns a string